# Test for significant differences in coefficient with different levels of fixed effects

Tags: r, statistical-significance, fixed-effects-model

I have two regressions with time and entity fixed effects (using felm in R) but the regressions have different levels of entity FEs (hospital FEs in the first and physician FEs in the second in my case):

$outcome_{it}=\beta_0 + \beta_1^H Treat_i +\delta_{t}+\delta_{h} $

$outcome_{it}=\beta_0 + \beta_2^P Treat_i +\delta_{t}+\delta_{p} $

where the delta terms are the different FEs. The samples and regressions are otherwise the same.

I want to test whether $\beta_1^H$ and $\beta_1^P$ are stat. significantly different from each other. I can think of how to bootstrap to build CIs and do it that way, but is there a more elegant/clean solution to test the difference?

Comment: Are you sure that only $\beta_1$ vs $\beta_2$ and $\delta_h$ vs $\delta_p$ are different and other 4 pairs (outcome, $\beta_0$, treat, and $\delta_t$ are the same?

Comment: Good point. I meant that the input variables and sample remain the same. The estimated parameters will all change with the new FEs.

Comment: Who is input variable? Who is output variable? Which variable is for hospital, physician?

Comment: By input I mean that the dependent and independent variables are the same for each regression. Just a different level of fixed effect (hospital vs physician). The data is on the patient level and each regression is for the same patients. Each patient observation has an associated hospital and physician. Treat is a binary indicator for whether they got a specific treatment and the outcome is binary for mortality.

Comment: I want to know if the treatment effect is statistically different when controlling for unobserved time-invariant heterogeneity at the hospital level versus at the physician level.

Comment: If the dependent variable and independent variables are the same, how can they be two different models. They should be the same model.

Comment: It depends if you define fixed effects as dependent variables. If you think of them as such (maybe as indicator/dummies for each physician vs hospital), then the dependent variables are not the same. If you think of fixed effects as a data transformation (within transformation), then the dependent variables are the same but the data undergoes different transformations (de-mean at the hospital or physician level). The terminology may be getting in the way here. I believe felm in R does a transformation if that matters.